# Python: Parsing through XML with mini dom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, text-parsing

I'm parsing through a decent sized xml file, and I ran into a problem. For some reason I cannot extract data even though I have done the *exact same thing* on different xml files before.

Here's a snippet of my code: (rest of the program, I've tested and they work fine)
EDIT: changed to include a testing try&except block

```
def parseXML():
    file = open(str(options.drugxml),'r')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    dom = parseString(data)
    druglist = dom.getElementsByTagName('drug')

    with codecs.open(str(options.csvdata),'w','utf-8') as csvout, open('DrugTargetRel.csv','w') as dtout:
        for entry in druglist:
        count = count + 1
        try:
            drugtype = entry.attributes['type'].value
            print count
        except:
            print count
            print entry
            drugidObj = entry.getElementsByTagName('drugbank-id')[0]
            drugid = drugidObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue
            drugnameObj = entry.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]
            drugname = drugnameObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue

            targetlist = entry.getElementsByTagName('target')
            for target in targetlist:
                targetid = target.attributes['partner'].value
                dtout.write((','.join((drugid,targetid)))+'\n')

            csvout.write((','.join((drugid,drugname,drugtype)))+'\n')
```

In case you're wondering what the XML file's schema roughly looks like, here's a rough god-awful sketch of the levels:

```
<drugs>
   <drug type='something' ...>
      <drugbank-id>
      <name>
      ...
      <targets>
         <target partner='something'>
```

Those that I typed in here, I need to extract from the XML file and stick it in csv files (as the code above shows), and the code has worked for different xml files before, not sure why it's not working on this one. I've gotten KeyError on 'type', I've also gotten indexing errors on line that extracts drugid even though EVERY drug has a drugid. What am I screwing up here?

EDIT: the stuff I'm extracting are guaranteed to be in each drug.

For anyone who cares, here's the link to the XML file I'm parsing:
http://www.drugbank.ca/system/downloads/current/drugbank.xml.zip

EDIT: After implementing a try & except block (see above) here's what I found out:
In the schema, there are sections called "drug interactions" that *also* have a subfield called *drug*. So like this:

```
 <drugs>
       <drug type='something' ...>
          <drugbank-id>
          <name>
          ...
          <targets>
             <target partner='something'>
          <drug-interactions>
             <drug>
```

I think that my line druglist = dom.getElementsByTagName('drug') is unintentionally picking those up as well -- I don't know how I could fix this... any suggestions?

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Yep, edited so that the most recent 2 errors that I encountered without changing much else besides adding/removing print statements.

Comment: Your code assumes that records always have the format you think they have. The KeyError just means a drug element didn't have a type attribute. Similar issue with the IndexError... the record didn't have the info you wanted. Try putting the "for entry in druglist:" block into a try/except block and then print the entry causing the problem. Does it look right? Long term, that except handler implements your failure policy (continue processing, report the record, or whatever).

Comment: @tdelaney that's what I thought could be causing the error at first but when I checked the data EVERY drug field comes with a type attribute, and EVERY drug MUST come with a drug id and a drug name. I checked this even with the data source. Every one of them have to be in there. That's why I'm stumped. I'll put in a try/except block and make some more checks.

Comment: I found some new information -- tdelaney, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Joe If drugs is a root element, which has only drug as subsequent elements use childNodes on drugs instead of getElementsByTagName.

Comment: @LazyDave ... why didn't I think of that. That should work better. If you put that in as answer I'll accept that.

Comment: I like @LazyDave's solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when parsin an xml, you can't rely on the fact that you know the structure. It's a good practise to find out structure in code.

So everytime you access elements or attributes, check before if there any. In your code it means following:

Make sure there's an attribute 'type' on a drug element:

```
drugtype = entry.attributes['type'].value if entry.attributes.has_key('type') else 'defaulttype'
```

Make sure getElementsByTagName doesn't returns empty array before accessing its elements:

```
drugbank-id = entry.getElementsByTagName('drugbank-id')
drugidObj = drugbank-id[0] if drugbank-id else None
```

Also before accessing childnodes make sure there are any:

```
if drugidObj.hasChildNodes:
    drugid = drugidObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Or use for loop to loop through them.

And when you call `getElementsByTagName` on the drugs elemet it returns all elements including the nested ones. To get only drug elements, which are dirrect children of drugs element you have to use `childNodes` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I had a feeling that maybe there was something weird happening due to running out of memory or something, so I rewrote the parser using an iterator over each drug and tried it out and got the program to complete without raising an exception.

Basically what I'm doing here is, instead of loading the entire XML file into memory, I parse the XML file for the beginning and end of each `<drug>` and `</drug>` tag. Then I parse that with the minidom each time.

The code might be a little fragile as I assume that each `<drug>` and `</drug>` pair are on their own lines. Hopefully it helps more than it harms though.

```
#!python
import codecs
from xml.dom import minidom

class DrugBank(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.fp = open(filename, 'r')

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        state = 0

        while True:
            line = self.fp.readline()

            if state == 0:
                if line.strip().startswith('<drug '):
                    lines = [line]
                    state = 1
                    continue

                if line.strip() == '</drugs>':
                    self.fp.close()
                    raise StopIteration()

            if state == 1:
                lines.append(line)
                if line.strip() == '</drug>':
                    return minidom.parseString("".join(lines))

with codecs.open('csvout.csv', 'w', 'utf-8') as csvout, open('dtout.csv', 'w') as dtout:
    db = DrugBank('drugbank.xml')
    for dom in db:
        entry = dom.firstChild
        drugtype = entry.attributes['type'].value
        drugidObj = entry.getElementsByTagName('drugbank-id')[0]
        drugid = drugidObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue
        drugnameObj = entry.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]
        drugname = drugnameObj.childNodes[0].nodeValue

        targetlist = entry.getElementsByTagName('target')
        for target in targetlist:
            targetid = target.attributes['partner'].value
            dtout.write((','.join((drugid,targetid)))+'\n')

        csvout.write((','.join((drugid,drugname,drugtype)))+'\n')
```

An interesting read that might help you out further is here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look at that. I eventually figured it out on my own too but I will try this out too. Thanks!